# Using Moq to test call to different class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

## The problem

I have the following method:

```
public void ParseRebootData(RebootDeviceDto rebootDeviceDto)
{
    if (rebootDeviceDto.RebootAtUtc.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow) <= 0) // if time is either now or in the past, reboot instantly
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rebooting machine now");
        await new Tasks.Reboot().RebootNow(); // <-- I want to test this line

    }
    else // schedule the reboot
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Scheduling reboot at {rebootDeviceDto.RebootAtUtc}");
        _backgroundJobClient.Schedule<Tasks.Reboot>(x => x.RebootNow(), rebootDeviceDto.RebootAtUtc);
    }
}
```

`_backgroundJobClient` is passed through by dependency injection in the constructor.

I want to test the line `await new Tasks.Reboot().RebootNow();` if it's being called, using Moq's `Verify` method.

## My question

Since `Tasks.Reboot` is just a class, which is not passed through dependency injection, I don't know if I can test this call.

One of the solutions might be to create a `TasksService` which I can override in my unit tests (which might not be a bad idea) but I want to know if this is possible at all, as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Moq, you can only provide mock objects from the outside. You cannot replace a static instantiation with another one.

There are other testing frameworks that can do this, e.g. the shims of Microsoft [Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2017). On the other hand, shims are supposed to be used with third-party-code. If you can change the code and inject a TasksService, this is the preferred method in order to decouple the code.